# Filter mapping for everything to Struts2 besides one servlet?

Tags: java, struts2, servlet-filters

I have a Struts2 (2.1.8.1) web application.  My web.xml looks like,

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

This is configured to map all requests to the struts filter.  I want to add a servlet in my web application.  I want to send all requests with a certain url pattern to that servlet.  I want everything else to go to my struts servlet.

I know I could only map "*.action" to the struts servlet, but I hate .action being on the end of all my URL's.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your struts.xml add:

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/ServletToExcludeFromStruts*"/>
```

The value be comma delimited as well for multiple exclusions. See http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/webxml.html