# JFreeChart image not refreshing in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart

I have one jsp page which contains two text fields Start Date and End Date. User will input start date and end date and then I will query the database for data between those dates. When I click submit, it will just forward it to the current page and I will pass the dates as parameters. So far so good, but the problem is the image jfreechart does not refresh unless i refresh the browser itself.

Here is my form.

```
  <form method="GET" action='monitor' name="check">
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>Start Date (dd/MM/yyyy format):</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="startDate"
  value="<%=startDate%>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>End Date (dd/MM/yyyy format):</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="endDate" value="<%=endDate%>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="submit" value="check"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>

  <img src="lineChart.png" width="600" height="400" border="0" usemap="#chart" />
```

Here is my inline code for generating the chart

```
   final File file1 = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath(".") + "/lineChart.png");
   ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
```

I tried doing writeChartAsPNG but it will overwrite the whole page. Page should still look like,

```
Start Date:
End Date: 

[ VIEW ] 

Monitor Data Chart
[  chart here ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll have to change things around pretty substantially to get the image to refresh inside the page when you click `View`, and you'll end up writing a fair bit of javascript

essentially what has to happen (which is pretty high level)

1. make `View` a regular button, instead of a submit on the form.
2. attach a click listener to the view button (check out the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for it's click function)
3. inside the listener, grab the values from the Start Date and End Date inputs
4. set the src attribute of the image (using a mechanism [like in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)) to a jsp or servlet, sending the start and end dates as get variables (in the query string like `?startdate= ... &enddate= ...`
5. in  that jsp or servlet, generate the chart and return the raw png output from jFreeChart with a content type of `image/png` (use `response.setContentType("text/png")`).  This will display the image in the img tag correctly, and you won't have to write a file out to the disk either.

this process will update the image every time you hit `View`, with the values you input into your form.

it's a lot of steps, and I can't really get into the nitty gritty of the implementation without knowing a whole lot more about your setup, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks I just passed the the start date and end date in the parameter of the chart. Like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092729/adding-graph-chart-to-a-buffer/13093044#13093044