# servlet not calling struts2 , web.xml conflict

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts2, web.xml

Here is my `web.xml` structure:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>       
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/testServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

In Jsp, I called the servlet like below.

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/testServlet?id=${someID}"
```

The problem is when I used like below, the servlet is called. When I changed `*.jsp` to `/*` in fliter mapping, it failed to call the servlet.

```
   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

but when I use `*.jsp`, then the calender using struts2-dojo plugin doesn't appear in jsp.

Comment: Is there any exception on the server?

Comment: no exception found on server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843548/filter-mapping-for-everthing-to-struts2-besides-one-servlet

Comment: WTQ? If you have the question, please, do it by editing your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude particular request path from handling it by Struts 2

[Preventing Struts from Handling a Request](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/static-content.html#StaticContent-PreventingStrutsfromHandlingaRequest)

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude `myServlet` mapping so that is does not pass from the filter dispatcher of struts.

In your struts.xml add:

`<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/ServletToExcludeFromStruts*"/>`

The value be comma delimited as well for multiple exclusions.

See http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/webxml.html ..

Help taken from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843548/filter-mapping-for-everthing-to-struts2-besides-one-servlet).